# How to add sites to "Your most popular sites" in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer

All of my icons in "Your Most Popular Sites" of IE9 appear to be [blank.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/46620806@N05/9511385052/) Sometimes I add some sites to it inadvertently.

And other problem I have is when I close IE9, all icons of the "Your Most Popular Sites" get blank again. It has to be with some register tweaks?

Comment: Sounds like you have configured IE9 to clear your history when you close it.

Comment: Do you know where could I setup that configuration?

Comment: Try setting IE9 to the default configuration.